# How to assign " to a variable in php?

Tags: php

I want to get date using date function but the date should comes between `"  "`. I want to assign `"` to a variable so that i can get my output by combining the two variables:

```
$td=""";

$td2="".date("m/d/Y")."";

$td3=""";

$date="$td"."$td2"."$td3";
```

Please help...?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about absolute language _basics_, on which one should read up in the manual. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to escape them, just wrap them in a single quote instead:

```
$td = '"';
$td2 = '"'.date("m/d/Y").'"';
$td3 = '"';
$date = $td.$td2.$td3;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape them

```
$td = "\"";
```

With the backslash, the character is treated as a character by any means necessary and is ignored by php, it wont be used to limiting strings or someting like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$td=""";
```

**OR**

```
$td = "\"";
```

Use backslash or single quotes .

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted, rather than duplicating them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "\" before " in your $td and $td3 variable.

```
$td="\"";
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted, rather than duplicating them.